# How to position tikzpicture in the vertical middle of a tabularray cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray

I want to place a `tikzpicture` in a `tabularray` cell but somehow it is not in the middle but offset to the upper half...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\resultgraphproportion}[3]{\fpeval{(#3-#1)/(#2-#1)}}

\newcommand{\resultgraphheight}{0.5}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showresultgraphT}{}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,\resultgraphheight);
        \node[gray] at (0,-0.1) {\tiny 20};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{lcc}
        \hline
        abc &   \showresultgraphT & great \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the `tikzpicture` appear in the vertical middle of the cell?

[image]

Comment: Alignment  uses the baseline.  Tikzpictures can use `[baseline=(coordinate)]`.  Howver, text is not centered about the baseline either, although the difference is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution centers a `\strut` within the tikzpicture, then uses its baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\resultgraphproportion}[3]{\fpeval{(#3-#1)/(#2-#1)}}

\newcommand{\resultgraphheight}{0.5}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showresultgraphT}{}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(phantom.base)]
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,\resultgraphheight);
        \node[gray, inner sep=0pt] at (0,-0.1) {\tiny 20};
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (phantom) at (current bounding box.center) {\strut};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{lcc}
        \hline
        abc &   \showresultgraphT & great \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. That works great and the text is also in the middle of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move image baseline position to its vertical center by use of image option `baseline=(current bounding box.center)`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\resultgraphproportion}[3]{\fpeval{(#3-#1)/(#2-#1)}}

\newcommand{\resultgraphheight}{0.5}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showresultgraphT}{}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,\resultgraphheight);
        \node[gray] at (0,-0.1) {\tiny 20};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{lcc}
        \hline
        abc &   \showresultgraphT & great \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Regarding your comment:

- figure is for sure vertical centered ...
- to see this, just draw borders around node with grey text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\resultgraphproportion}[3]{\fpeval{(#3-#1)/(#2-#1)}}

\newcommand{\resultgraphheight}{0.5}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showresultgraphT}{}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,\resultgraphheight);
        \node[draw, gray, font=\tiny] at (0,-0.1) {20};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines,
                 colspec = {lcc},
                 }
        abc &   \showresultgraphT & great \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Now result is:

[image]

If you like that vertical distance between second node content (number 20) and bottom table `\hline` is the same as is between orange box ant top `\hline`, than you need to redesign your image: remove vertical separation between node contents and its border and manually align its baselines as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\resultgraphproportion}[3]{\fpeval{(#3-#1)/(#2-#1)}}

\newcommand{\resultgraphheight}{0.5}
\NewDocumentCommand{\showresultgraphT}{}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(([yshift=3pt] current bounding box.base)}] % <--- changed
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0) rectangle (1,\resultgraphheight);
        \node[inner ysep=0pt, % <--- added
              gray, font=\tiny] at (0,-0.1) {20};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines,
                 colspec = {lcc},
                 }
        abc &   \showresultgraphT & great \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Now both vertical distances between image and text to row borders are the same.

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for that solution. However, the space under the image (white space under the 20) is still bigger than at the top...

Comment: Thanks. What confused me as well was that moving the baseline to the middle makes the text appear shifted up. Can I move the baseline to the `current bounding box.center` + an offset?

Comment: @mrCarnivore, unfortunately this not possible. However what is wrong with proposed solution? As I see, it is simple and works fine ...

Comment: I may have not phrased my question perfectly. But what I meant is that the text needs to also stay in the middle with the tikzpicture. With the tikzpicture now being perfectly in the middle in your last solution, the text is not. This is because the baseline of the text is in the middle of the line. That makes the text be visibly shifted up.

Comment: @mrCarnivore, but my proposed solution fulfil all your requirements: text is vertical centered, image is vertical centered, so it is not clear what expected more.

Comment: The text is not vertically centered. The baseline of the text is vertically centered. This makes the text appear to be too high up. The solution from John Kormylo provides the text vertically centered. But still thank you for your effort and your solution. You helped me understand TikZ more!